# At import rule in style sheet

Tags: error

I have an at import rule in my main style sheet. @import url("base.css"); However its not importing the base.css. The base.css is in the same template group.

Any suggestion?

Jim Breen

Comment: If any of the answers below helped, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but have you checked the url path? You should use a full path for the base.css file on the server like...

http://www.mysite.com/css/base.css

And since the css file is in a template group I would also suggest including the "index.php" part of the URL so that htaccess won't mess around with it.

- Bob.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from "the same template group" that both the main style sheet and base.css are both in your EE templates. Are you using the template group and template name in an EE tag in your import rule?

`@import url('{path=home/base}');`

or

`@import url('{stylesheet='channel/channel_css'}');`

Comment: I think I am going to take your advise and not use the @import rule at all. I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you've created a 'CSS' templates to run your CSS through? If you're using @import then I think you'll either need to use the full path to the other CSS file:

```
@import(/path/to/css);
```

Or you can use regular path variables using the template_group/template pattern:

```
@import({path='template_group/template'});
```

As a general tip though [using @import is best avoided](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) if possible from a performance point of view. It will ad an extra roundtrip to your page loads and in IE it will see the imports load out of order which can cause issues. If you have multiple stylesheets you'll be better off using something like [Minimee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/minimee) to minimise, combine, and compress your CSS files for much better performance.

You can also link to regular CSS files without needing to run through CSS specific templates.